# iPad application download files from password-protected directory

Tags: cocoa, url, ipad, password-protection

I have a password-protected directory on a running server. I would like to download some file(s) from this directory (using a URL) to the Documents directory of my iPad application. How do I send the password of the directory I am trying to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSURLConnection`. If the server asks for a password, the connection's delegate will be sent a `-connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` message. Use it to supply password to the server and continue the download.